# data with request completionhandler not always called

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurl

I am making an app where you can search for movies with the API of http://www.omdbapi.com/.

The problem I am having is with the completion handler of dataTaskWithRequest. If you click on one of the collectionView cell, you will go to the detailView of that selected movie. However it doesn't work all the time. I get an error saying: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping. And that's because it doesn't go in the completion handler of dataTaskWithRequest but goes straight to the detailVC and try passing data in the title label, genre label, etc but there is no data.

I hope you guys know what the problem is, because I have tried and I don't see what the problem is.

Or, does this problem occurs because of something before? Because first I retrieve data from http://www.omdbapi.com/ using "by search" instead of "by ID". And from there I retrieve the ID and from that ID I retrieve data for my detailVC.

Here is my code:

```
 // Go to detail view of selected movie
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedMovieId = self.IDs[indexPath.row]

    chosenMovieId = selectedMovieId

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
}

// Preparations before going to the detail view of selected movie
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        _ = self.movieInfoFrom(searchMovie: chosenMovieId, segue: segue)
    }
}


func movieInfoFrom(searchMovie movieId: String, segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let movieUrlString = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(movieId)&y=&plot=full&r=json"
    let url = NSURL(string: movieUrlString)
    print(movieUrlString)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let urlTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            // Convert data to JSON
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)

            let title = swiftyJSON["Title"].string!
            let runTime = swiftyJSON["Runtime"].string!
            let genre = swiftyJSON["Genre"].string!
            let plot = swiftyJSON["Plot"].string!
            let rating = swiftyJSON["imdbRating"].string!
            let year = swiftyJSON["Year"].string!
            let poster = swiftyJSON["Poster"].string

            self.infoResult = ["\(title)", "\(runTime)", "\(genre)", "\(plot)", "\(rating)", "\(year)"]
            print("\(self.infoResult)")

            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieDetailController

            destinationVC.movieDetails = self.infoResult
            destinationVC.moviePoster = poster
        }
    }

    urlTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix your code and explain with some comments:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedMovieId = self.IDs[indexPath.row]

    chosenMovieId = selectedMovieId

    self.movieInfoFrom(searchMovie: chosenMovieId)
}

// Preparations before going to the detail view of selected movie
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieDetailController

            destinationVC.movieDetails = self.infoResult
            destinationVC.moviePoster = poster
    }
}


func movieInfoFrom(searchMovie movieId: String) {

    let movieUrlString = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(movieId)&y=&plot=full&r=json"
    let url = NSURL(string: movieUrlString)
    print(movieUrlString)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    // This is asynchronously, you can put a loading here 
    let urlTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        // Got response, stop loading here
        if error == nil {

            // Convert data to JSON
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)

            let title = swiftyJSON["Title"].string!
            let runTime = swiftyJSON["Runtime"].string!
            let genre = swiftyJSON["Genre"].string!
            let plot = swiftyJSON["Plot"].string!
            let rating = swiftyJSON["imdbRating"].string!
            let year = swiftyJSON["Year"].string!

            // You can save the poster as local variable
            let poster = swiftyJSON["Poster"].string

            self.infoResult = ["\(title)", "\(runTime)", "\(genre)", "\(plot)", "\(rating)", "\(year)"]
            print("\(self.infoResult)")

            // This should be call on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
            }


        }
    }

    urlTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked by rearranging some line of codes and functions. Could you explain to me why this solution solve the problem? Is it because I call perfomSegue too soon?

Comment: That is because your URL task is asynchronous, which means that it return immediately and the preparation for segue has finished before your task has ended.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. If I use breakpoints in my code before all the changes, I can see it go to the function prepareForSegue. And from there it goes to the function movieInfoFrom and if the URL task is finished it goes in the completion handler and after that it shows the detailView on the simulator. Does this not mean that prepareForSegue is finished when it has done the block of code in the function movieInfoFrom?

Comment: No. It means that your network is fast enough to get a response quickly maybe... prepareForSegue definitely finish before your block of code is executed because it run asynchronously on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, with safe optionals

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    chosenMovieId = self.IDs[indexPath.row]
    movieInfoFrom(searchMovie: chosenMovieId)

}

func movieInfoFrom(searchMovie movieId: String) {

    let movieUrlString = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(movieId)&y=&plot=full&r=json"
    let url = NSURL(string: movieUrlString)
    print(movieUrlString)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let urlTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil && data != nil {

            // Convert data to JSON
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)

            let title = swiftyJSON["Title"].string ?? ""
            let runTime = swiftyJSON["Runtime"].string ?? ""
            let genre = swiftyJSON["Genre"].string ?? ""
            let plot = swiftyJSON["Plot"].string ?? ""
            let rating = swiftyJSON["imdbRating"].string ?? ""
            let year = swiftyJSON["Year"].string ?? ""
            let poster = swiftyJSON["Poster"].string

            self.infoResult = ["\(title)", "\(runTime)", "\(genre)", "\(plot)", "\(rating)", "\(year)"]
            print("\(self.infoResult)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: poster)
            }
        }
    }
    urlTask.resume()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail", let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MovieDetailController {

        destinationVC.movieDetails = self.infoResult
        destinationVC.moviePoster = sender as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. By rearranging some code of line and function it worked. Could you explain to me why this solution solve the problem? Is it because I called performSegue too soon?